# Pointer Initalization

Tags: c++, pointers

In the Code below:

```
char data[128] = "Just A Test \0";
char *cTest2 = data;
char *cTest3 = &data[0];
```

What is the difference between cTest2 and cTest3?
When would you use one method of initialization over the other?

Comment: You do not need the \0. It will be added automatically for you

Comment: The operations effectively cancel each other out. You could do `char* test = &(&data[0])[0];` if you wanted.

Comment: There only would be a difference if `data` was not dereferencable. But in this case, as already stated, there is no difference.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference; since a decent compiler would yield the same code, which you use would be according to personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

Effectively there is no difference, but your code should reflect what you mean.

If you want to address the array as a whole, use the style of `cTest2`.
If you want to address the first element, use `cTest3`.

Answer (score 2):

There is exactly no difference at all. The C++ specification says :

#### *5.2.1 Subscripting*

*A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a postfix expression. One of the expressions
shall have the type “array of T” or “pointer to T” and the other shall have unscoped enumeration
or integral type. The result is of type “T.” The type “T” shall be a completely-defined object type. The
expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2))*

That means that `data[0]` is *by definition* the same as `*data`, so always *by definition*, `&(data[0])` **is** `data`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no great sense to include zero character in the string literal

```
char data[128] = "Just A Test \0";
                              ^^^
```

String literals already contain the terminating zero.

As for the pointer declarations then there is no difference between these two

```
char *cTest2 = data;
char *cTest3 = &data[0];
```

A character array used in expressions is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. So these two declarations are equivalent.

However I would prefer the first declaration because it is more clear. I would use the second declaration only in case when the pointer has to be initialized by the address of some element of the array except the first element. For example

```
char *cTest3 = &data[5];
```

But in this case there is no sense to dereference expression `data + 5` because `data[5]` is equivalent to `*( data + 5 )` and `&data[5]` is equivalent to `&*( data + 5 )`. Though when the two operators & and * follow each other the compiler may omit the dereference of the pointer.

According to the C Standard (6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators)

> 3. ...If the operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that
>      operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both
>      were omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply
>      and the result is not an lvalue....

So actually I would write

```
char *cTest3 = data + 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have somewhere a

```
char *cTest4 = &data[5];
```

or a similar scheme I would vote for cTest3. Otherwise cTest2 looks cleaner.